# parallel independent iteration of elements in an array

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, iteration, parfor

I want to iterate all the elements independently (same condition for all elements though). I want to stop the iteration when the value stops changing. I will post the part of my code. According to some research, I figured that it can also be done using parfor loop but i don't know how to implement it. Can anyone please correct my code? Thanks in Advance.

```
probability = (ones(1,2048) .* 1/2048);

Tij = sum(StateTransitionfwd); %gives us an array of 2048 elements.

probability = ((probability * StateTransitionbwd) - (Tij .* probability));

threshold = (ones(1,2048) .* 0.05);

old = zeros(1,2048);

new = zeros(1,2048);

while(1)

    probability = ((probability * StateTransitionbwd) - (Tij .* probability));

    new = probability;

    if old-new <= threshold

        break
    end
    old = probability;

end
```

So basically I want the steady state probability (where it is not changing anymore)

Answer (score 0):

For one you cannot parallellise while loops.

To implement a `parfor` loop make sure of the following:
 - All variables must be defined before the parfor loop. Thus define output variables before the loop.
 - All iterations must be absolutely independent of one another.

The second condition is not fulfilled in your case, since you are constantly updating the variable `new`, making it not independent.

I'd not even parallellise this code, since it's designed to break up before it went through all elements, but for the sake of argument I'll try this:

```
parfor ii = 1:length(Tij)
    probability{ii} = ((probability * StateTransitionbwd) - (Tij .* probability));
end
```

Either use a cell or a matrix, whichever is more useful for your work.
Now you can go ahead and use a simple `if` to find your threshold:

```
for ii = 1:length(probability)-1
     if probability(ii+1)-probability(ii)<threshold
        break
     end
end
```

As for your while loop stop condition: it's dangerous to let a loop run uncontrolled to some condition, as you do. It's rather easy to get stuck in an infinite loop. Use an additional condition `MaxIt` for the maximum number of iterations to do before terminating, regardless of the other condition.

```
while probability<threshold && MaxIt<someNumber
    your code
end
```

Also you are checking for the validity of a full array.

```
A = logical([1;0]);
while A
    B=1;
end
C = logical([1;1]);
while C
    D=1;
end
```

The first while loop will not run, since one of its entries is not true; the second loop is an infinite loop now. If you want to terminate each row as soon as the condition is met, put the while loop inside a for loop over each row instead. That forloop can be parallellised if you put the while loop into a function, see the parfor documentation for that.

Comment: @visser Thanks a lot for taking the time out. You are right its not working. Can I please ask for a suggestion then what to do as I have  no clue atm. I just want to iterate all of the elements (probabilities) in an array independent to each other. I want them to stop when convergence is reached which will reach at different times for all the elements. Anu suggestion will be really really helpful.

Comment: You cannot independently calculate things which stop when convergence is reached, that violates the 'each iteration has to be independent' condition. Do not parallellise this code, just stick with the while loop, since it is probably faster. The parallel version I presented still calculates everything and then has to search for the condition, as opposed to your original while loop, which does a calculation and then checks the validity of the break statement. Parfor loops do not execute consecutively, e.g. it might do ii = 1 5 3 4 2 as iterations instead of ii = 1 2 3 4 5, which you want.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but the problem is its not stopping. I even left it for two days but still matlab shows busy. So i think maybe its possible that my condition is not meeting.  Do you think my original code is doing what i actually want?

Comment: It should. Using while(1) is tricky though, as it's easy to get stuck in an infinite loop. Try using "while old-new<threshold" this gets rid of the if statement and has a better stopping condition. Might be that your array never converges to the threshold value though. Check this by changing to a for-loop with e.g. 1M iterations and check the condition "old-new" manually.

Comment: So I did this.                                                                                        threshold = (ones(1,2048) .* 0.05);
 old = probability;
new = zeros(1,2048);
  while old - new <= threshold
  
      probability = ((probability * StateTransitionbwd) - (Tij .* probability));
      
      new = probability;
  
  end

Comment: I was not paying attention. You're checking a full array for validity as a stopping condition, and this stops only and only if ALL values inside your array are true. I still suspect your array is just not converging, use the forloop to check that. As for the while loop in your previous comment: use "while old-new >= threshold" of course, since you're approaching your condition from above.